# increment unreachable in for loop in c# method

Tags: c#, increment, unreachable-code

I've got this **unreachable code** in this `for` loop

```
public IActionResult List(int id) {
    for (id = 0; id <= 1000; id++) {
        var fil = _repoFil.GetById(id).Result;
        var listafiliali = new List<FilialeVM>();

        foreach (var filiale in fil) {
            var filialeVM = _mapper.Map<FilialeVM>(fil);
            listafiliali.Add(filialeVM);
        }

        return View(listafiliali);
    }

    return View();
}
```

the increment `id++` **is unreachable**

Comment: It is unreachable because you `return View(listafiliali);` on the first iteration

Comment: @Rafalon thanks but how can i return that variable?

Comment: Why do you need the loop when you return the first value found?

Comment: Which one? It is quite unclear what you want to achieve  here

Comment: What is the *original problem*, please? What are you trying to implement? You ignore the `id` passed, you don't use `for` loop (you return from the first iteration) and you never call `return View();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return your View AFTER your loop finished

```
public IActionResult List(int id) {
    var listafiliali = new List<FilialeVM>();

    for (id = 0; id <= 1000; id++) {
        var fil = _repoFil.GetById(id).Result;            
        foreach (var filiale in fil) {
            var filialeVM = _mapper.Map<FilialeVM>(fil);
            listafiliali.Add(filialeVM);
        }            
    }

    if(listafiliali.Count > 0)
       return View(listafiliali);

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have *several problems* with your code:

1. You *ignore* `id` passed: imagine that I call `List(1234)`, `1234` will be ignored as well as `789` in `List(789)`
2. You *don't loop* over `id` since you return after the `1st` loop
3. You'll *never reach* `return View();` code: you enter loop and return from it.

I guess, you want something like this:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  public IActionResult List(int id) {
    // for given id we collect all corresponding FilialeVM items
    var listafiliali = _repoFil
      .GetById(id)                                // items correspond to given id
      .Result
      .Select(fil => _mapper.Map<FilialeVM>(fil)) // mapped to FilialeVM
      .ToList();                                  // organized as list

    // If we have any item in listafiliali, view them, otherwise use default View()
    return listafiliali.Any()
      ? View(listafiliali)
      : View();
  }
```

Or if you don't want `id` to be passed but to scan `id = [0..1000]` range:

```
  public IActionResult List() {
    // for id in [0..1000] range we collect all corresponding FilialeVM items
    var listafiliali = Enumerable
      .Range(0, 1000 + 1)
      .SelectMany(id => _repoFil
         .GetById(id)                                 // items correspond to given id
         .Result
         .Select(fil => _mapper.Map<FilialeVM>(fil))) // mapped to FilialeVM
      .ToList();                                      // organized as list

    // If we have any item in listafiliali, view them, otherwise use default View()
    return listafiliali.Any()
      ? View(listafiliali)
      : View();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unreachable because you have this line: `return View(listafiliali);` in your for loop. The method returns and terminated its execution in the first for-loop iteration as soon as it hits the before mentioned return.